# iscrollview and jquery mobile popups bottom content hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, iscrollview

I'm using iscrollview in a jqm app. I have various popups that use the native jqm popup widget. With iOS7 (had same problem with 6.0) on an iPhone 4 the proper scrolling is only activated on changing the orientation?? When the app first loads, in portrait orientation, the lower part of the content won't scroll into view but changing orientation the popup changes size and position as it should and all the content is scrollable. Change back to portrait - the popup content is now scrolling properly?

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
<div class="header" data-role="header">
            <h1>Stuff</h1></div>
   <div class="content" data-role="content" data-iscroll>
   <h3>Heading here</h3>
      <p>Lots of copy here</p>
      <p>Lots of copy here</p>
      <p>Lots of copy here</p>
      <p>Lots of copy here</p>
      <p>Lots of copy here</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Some basic css:

```
.ui-content {
padding: 0 !important;
}

.ui-listview {
margin: 0 !important;
}

div.iscroll-scroller {
width: 100% !important;
}

.ui-popup .ui-content {
height: 150px !important;
}
```

I've read a lot of the documentation for iscrollview, particularly about the refresh() of iscrollview but I'm not sure how to implement this. Do I need to make changes to the various parameters in the js file or do I need to implement some other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the popUp fixed size! Look here: http://www.gajotres.net/using-iscroll-with-jquery-mobile/